# C Array of Random Numbers Storage

Tags: c, c99, c89

Hi I want to know is there a way to store randnumber without prompting user for input. In this example we want user to store 16 randnumbers in array `storerand` without prompting the user for randnums for example:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
void main() {
    int randnum;
    int i=0;
    int storerand[16]; // storing randnumbers 
    randnum=rand();

        while(i <16){
            storerand[i]=randnum; // why is this not storing 16 rand number how can i store 16 randnumbers 
         i++;
        }
        return 0;
```

Comment: Your loop counter `i` does not appear to be incremented anywhere in your code. What do you think this means for your loop?

Comment: Do you want the 16 values to be exactly the same random number, or do you want to generate a new random number for each slot?

Comment: @paddy they can be different numbers

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to generate random numbers in C is to use the `rand()` function which comes with `<stdlib.h>`. Note that if you do not seed with the time library, you will receive the same random numbers every time you run your program.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (void) {
    //Uses system time to seed a proper random number.
    srand(time(NULL));
    //rand() generates a random integer
    int a = rand();
    //Use mod to restrict range:
    int b = rand()%5; //random integer from 0-4
    return 0;
}
```

You also need to make sure to increment your index i within your while loop.

```
while(i < 16) {
    storerand[i] = rand(); 
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You initialise `randnum` with a random value here:

```
randnum=rand();
```

And then you run your loop to put its value into each slot of your array.  That means you're putting the *same* value into each slot.

```
while(i <16){
    storerand[i]=randnum;
    i++;
}
```

The solution is to call `rand()` each time around the loop:

```
for( i = 0; i < 16; i++ ) {
    storerand[i] = rand();
}
```